# Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS and expand to maximum size in responsive parent div without overflow

Tags: html, css

I want to create a responsive `<div>` that can change its width/height as the window's width and height changes, while **maintaining its aspect ratio** and **filling the maximum space available** in a parent div with **no overflow**. The parent div is responsive, with `height:100vh` and `width:100vw`.

Are there any CSS rules that would allow me to maintain aspect ratio, and expand to fill this `<div>`?

[image]

**When the window width > window height:**
I want the responsive div to have **horizontal aspect-ratio** [16/9] (horizontal video) and to take up maximum space in the 100vh parent div without overflow.

**When the window width < window height**: I want the responsive div to have **vertical aspect-ratio** [9/16] (vertical video) and to take up maximum space in the 100vh div **without overflowing the div**.

If there is a pure CSS solution to this, I would be so grateful.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```css
.parent {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background: blue;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 9/16) {
  .child {
    aspect-ratio: 9/16;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .child {
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <video class="child"></video>
</div>
```

I can't make the video take up maximum space in the parent without overflow.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please post what you have tried (HTML and CSS) so we may best help you here

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the post now to have an image and code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note this answer has been edited in response to the OP’s comment**

This snippet demonstrates the **problem**. The inner `<div>` stays within its container when the container is very wide or very tall, but not when the container is squarer.

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid mediumvioletred;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.wide {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.less-wide {
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tall {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
}

.less-tall {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
}

.video {
  background: lavenderblush;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wide .video, .less-wide .video {    /* you would use @media (orientation: landscape) { .video{} } instead */
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

.tall .video, .less-tall .video {    /* you would use @media (orientation: portrait) { .video{} } instead */
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent wide">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent less-wide">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent tall">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent less-tall">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
```

If the inside element is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) instead of a `<div>`, we can use `object-fit: contain;` and the problem is trivial.

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid mediumvioletred;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.wide {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.less-wide {
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tall {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
}

.less-tall {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
}

video {
  background: lavenderblush;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent wide">
  <video>
    <source src="https://donald.net.au/bugs/16x9.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  </video>
</div>

<div class="parent less-wide">
  <video>
    <source src="https://donald.net.au/bugs/16x9.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  </video>
</div>

<div class="parent tall">
  <video>
    <source src="https://donald.net.au/bugs/9x16.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  </video>
</div>

<div class="parent less-tall">
  <video>
    <source src="https://donald.net.au/bugs/9x16.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  </video>
</div>
```

The thing about replaced elements is that they have an intrinsic aspect ratio. It would be nice if the `object-fit` behaviour could also be used for a **non-replaced** element with an `aspect-ratio` specified in CSS, but I don't believe it can, at least not yet. `aspect-ratio` is fairly new to CSS, so perhaps this will happen in time.

But do you really need to make it work with a `<div>`? Perhaps the solution is to put your video directly inside your parent, rather than having another `<div>` in-between?

Comment: Brett, thank you for the help.

The parent div should be responsive with height 100vh and 100vw. Apologies, I’ve updated my question to clarify this.

When I run your snippet and change the parent `div` to `width: 100vw` and `height:100vh` the child div overflows the parent when I adjust the parent div size. Is there a way for me to keep within parent and maintain aspect ratio?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it properly, you want to rotate the video when it's in portrait mode to fit a bigger height, which could be solved by a media query:

```css
yourdiv{
    width:100%; /* to be as big as possible without overflowing */
}
yourvideo{
    object-fit:contain; /*To avoid deforming the video*/
}
    
@media (orientation: portrait){
    yourdiv{
        transform: rotate(90deg); /*change the video to 9:16 when it's in portrait mode (width < height) */
    }
}
```

However, if this isn't what you're looking for, try to give more information on what you want to do (f.e. I want to keep the video horizontal but just adapt it to a portrait screen).

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions that don't meet site basic requirements.